# How to send OrgChart info via Ajax

Tags: getorgchart

I want to know how can I send info ubicated in my orgChart to a database, I've to get into the GetOrgChart JS code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with ASP.NET you can use the following example as a starting point: https://github.com/GetOrgChart/ASP.NET-MVC